# Why isn't intelephense in Laravel middleware recognizing the function from my User model?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I made a piece of middleware that is responsible to check the permission a user has.  I implemented a hasPermission function in my User model. But when I try to use it via the `auth()->user` I get the following error, why is this happening?

[image]

I implemented this method in my User Model

```
public function hasPermission($permission)
{
    return in_array($this->permissions(), $permission);
}
```

And this is the middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class VerifyPermission
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasPermission($permission)) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        abort(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean "intelephense" doesn't recognize it. Do you get any errors when actually _running_ this code?

Comment: Yeah it's intelephense the code works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `user()` method has a return type of `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null` which is an interface that your user class implements. This is because it might return different models based on the guard you're using but they all have to implement `Authenticatable`.

I'm not aware of an easy way to change this globally, but you could save the user in a variable and add a phpDoc block:

```
/** @var \App\User */
$user = auth()->user();
```

This should get picked up by intelephense and show the correct methods.

Comment: Well that does work, but this doesn't look very neat. But I suppose that wasn't my question.

Comment: I agree. But since the problem is a comment and not a PHP type hint you might be able to do it by overriding the `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` in the container and replacing it with a class that inherits it and has its own `user()` method with a more precise type in the phpDoc block (and nothing else). But if Laravel ever adds PHP type hints to that method it might break things.